# How do I write to and read from a mocked file object in python, with mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to write a string to a mocked file object in the python [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) library, but it turns out that my method of writing to the mock object does not persist anything, even in memory, it seems.

I'm trying like this in the ipython shell:

```
In [1]: import mock
In [2]: fnopen = mock.mock_open()
In [3]: filehandle = fnopen()
In [4]: filehandle.write('ABC')
In [5]: filehandle.read()
Out[5]: ''
```

As you can see, I don't get the expected `'ABC'`, when executing `f.read()`, but instead an empty string.

What am I doing or understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No mock needed.

If what you want for your test is an in-memory file like object you could use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> file_like = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> file_like.write('ABC')
>>> file_like.seek(0)
>>> file_like.read()
'ABC'
```

Answer (score 1):

`mock.mock_open()` returns a `MagicMock` object, which means you wouldn't be able to read back the contents you write to it since it's not replicating the functionality of `open`, only the signature.

However, you can check that the `filehandle.write` was called with the correct arguments by using:

```
filehandle.write.assert_called_with('ABC')
```

As for why you'd do this, I'm uncertain, since you're essentially testing the mock library. Although I expect you've not shared your real code.

Source: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#mock-open

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies the scope of the mock library a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use param read_data in method mock_open:

```
m = mock.mock_open()
m = mock.mock_open(read_data='abc')
f = m()
```

Comment: Yes, saw this one in the docs, but it does not do what I want, since it requires me to "write" the data upon setting up the mock object, while I need to be able to let my objects write to it in the normal way. Thanks anyway!